# How to create a 3D Map with multiple layers?

Tags: qgis, layers, 3d-model, 3d-map

This is a Generic question, if it is not applicable please delete.

I was wondering if it was possible to make a 3D map (such as seen below) on QGIS version 3.10.0

[image]

The image is basically showing sediment samples and the estimated thickness of oily sediment at each sample.

Comment: I know this is a question about QGIS, but is it possible anywhere?  It doesn't seem to fit well either with the concept of 3-D map (a surface) or 3-D model, though closer to the second (the expanded surfaces), but the isopach map in the middle seems incongruous.     Is the isopach in the middle important? could it perhaps be at the top (floating above)?

Comment: This map is produced with Golden Surfer, I think that you can make something similar with a 3D view imported to QGIS print layout.